# How to remove a specific last character in a String

Tags: haskell

I want to remove the last character of a String, if it's a "!"

I know I want base cases, ie. if the string is empty:

`remove [] = []`

How do I index the last character?
Using:

`last`

And, what's the best way to create an 'if, then' loop for this problem?

Should I use guards? `|`

Answer (score 7):

The Haskell way of solving this is with a recursion and pattern matching:

```
remove "" = ""                   -- obvious
remove "!" = ""                  -- that's what we're here for
remove (x:xs) = (x : remove xs)  -- keep the head, proceed to the tail
```

Any attempts with `last` and conditional constructions will be less elegant and efficient.

Comment: You don't need that third case of `[x]`.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson you're right, thanks! (Fixed)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do this with a loop. Instead of such imperative thinking you can take a higher-level view and compose the program from several *higher-order functions*, getting this one-liner,

```
import Data.List (tails)

foo :: String -> String
foo  =  (take 1 =<<) . takeWhile (/= "!") . tails
 --  =  concat . map (take 1) . takeWhile (/= "!") . tails
```

or with list comprehensions,

```
foo xs  =  [c | (c:_) <- takeWhile (/= "!") $ tails xs]
```

`tails` repeatedly takes `tail`s of the input list, `takeWhile` gets rid of the final `'!'`, if any, and `concatMap (take 1)` reconstitutes the string back from its `tails`:

```
concatMap (take 1) . tails
```

is an identity operation on lists, and we're getting in on the action, in the middle.

Comment: In this case `tails` looks completely redundant (useless complexity), and your code removes `!zxcv` from `asdf!zxcv` which it is not supposed to.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda you are factually wrong. it does no such thing. run the code instead of trying to judge it on paper / in your head. `tails` is what makes it _not_ to do what you thought it did.

Comment: `*Main> foo "asdf!zxcv"`  ~~> `"asdf!zxcv"`   and `foo "hello there!!"` ~~> `"hello there!"` fwiw.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson thank you for taking a look.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda have you had a chance to see the above comments? maybe you'd wish to remove your erroneous comment so it's not confusing for the newbies?